# PopUpPanel With ComboBox Getting Detached

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

With Mouse Scroll, the popup panel is not getting moved along with the window and it looks detached with the textbox of the combobox.[image]

Forget About My Project.. Even In vaadin offical demo site - http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ComboBoxPlain i can see this combobox issue. Attached is the image.[image]

Comment: Can you post the code of your PopUpPanel nad ComboBox?

Comment: There is no separate code for PopUpPanel & ComboBox. Its a regular Vaadin ComboBox and it behaves this way. Here i am not using any custom component that i can present you any code. The same follows even if i create only a combobox in my dummy vaadin project. It's a vaadin issue which seems to be there that the PopUpPanel Of ComboBox doesn't move with window on mouse scroll..

Comment: Could be circumvented if the popup would close on mouseout. This could probably be done with some javascript glue.

Comment: There is no handle exposed to hide/show combobox popup.